# Passing arguments to a function using async/await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, testing, async-await, testcafe

I'm trying to pass arguments to a function that uses async/await. I've defined my function like so

```
// common.js

export const myAsyncFunc = async (t, textA, textB) => {
  await t
    .typeText('#input-1', textA)
    .typeText('#input-2', textB);
};
```

However, when I try to import this function to another file, like so, I can't pass it `t` because `t is not defined`:

```
// index.js

import { myAsyncFunc } from './common'

myAsyncFunc(t, textA, textB)
```

Is it possible to just pass in my `textA` and `textB` arguments (possibly with currying or another way) with async/await?

**EDIT:** So this is being run as part of the test cafe library. It looks like `t` comes from when `testcafe chrome client/__tests__/` is run, rather than being imported in the `common.js` file.

Comment: `t` is thus a dependency?

Comment: Where is `t` defined?

Comment: Well, you haven't defined `t`, so it's not defined, which is what I think the error message is actually saying.

Comment: myAsyncFunction(t, await textA, await textB) ?

Comment: @Jonasw Yeah, I've never seen an error which states "is not undefined". I think the error is actually "is not defined", or "is undefined", because it's trying to run functions on `t`, which is undefined (at least from the little code provided).

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo. Should read `is not defined`

Answer (score 8):

You are importing/exporting `myAsyncFunc`, but in your code you are calling `myAsyncFunction`.

Also, you are chaining

```
.typeText('#input-1', textA)
.typeText('#input-2', textB);
```

But I think `.typeText` returns a promise, right? So you should:

```
export const myAsyncFunc = async (t, textA, textB) => {
  await t.typeText('#input-1', textA);
  await t.typeText('#input-2', textB);
};
```

Other than that, the code is working just fine, **assuming you defined `t` somewhere**, as pointed out in the comments.